# Python Snakes game: 2 colors in 1 class

Tags: python

I am currently working on a little Snakes game and I got stuck while trying to code the apple. I use a class called `Segment` which defines the segment color within its constructor (`__init__`).

However, I want to use the `Segment` class for the apple as well. I used it for `snake_segments` and now I want it for `apple_segments`. I did that but the color is still white and I don't know how to make it green while still making the snake white.

```
import pygame
import random
import time

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

segment_width = 16
segment_height = 16
segment_margin = 4

x_change = segment_width + segment_margin
y_change = 0


class Segment(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([segment_width, segment_height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

        if self.rect.left < screen_rect.left:
            temp_rect = self.rect.copy()
            temp_rect.x += screen_rect.width
            screen.blit(self.image, temp_rect)
        elif self.rect.right > screen_rect.right:
            temp_rect = self.rect.copy()
            temp_rect.x -= screen_rect.width
            screen.blit(self.image, temp_rect)

        if self.rect.top < screen_rect.top:
            temp_rect = self.rect.copy()
            temp_rect.y += screen_rect.height
            screen.blit(self.image, temp_rect)
        elif self.rect.bottom > screen_rect.bottom:
            temp_rect = self.rect.copy()
            temp_rect.y -= screen_rect.height
            screen.blit(self.image, temp_rect)


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption('Snakes')

allspriteslist = pygame.sprite.Group()

snake_segments = []
for i in range(3):
    x = 400 - (segment_width + segment_margin) * 1
    y = 200
    segment = Segment(x, y)
    snake_segments.append(segment)
    allspriteslist.add(segment)

apple_segments = []
for i in range(1):
    x = 200 - (segment_width + segment_margin) * 1
    y = 100
    segment = Segment(x, y)
    apple_segments.append(segment)
    allspriteslist.add(segment)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_change = (segment_width + segment_margin) * -1
            y_change = 0
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = (segment_width + segment_margin)
            y_change = 0
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            x_change = 0
            y_change = (segment_height + segment_margin) * -1
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            x_change = 0
            y_change = (segment_height + segment_margin)

old_segment = snake_segments.pop()
allspriteslist.remove(old_segment)

x = snake_segments[0].rect.x + x_change
y = snake_segments[0].rect.y + y_change

if x < screen_rect.left:
    x += screen_rect.width
elif x + segment_width + segment_margin > screen_rect.right:
    x -= screen_rect.width

if y < screen_rect.top:
    y += screen_rect.height
elif y + segment_height + segment_margin > screen_rect.bottom:
    y -= screen_rect.height

segment = Segment(x, y)

snake_segments.insert(0, segment)
allspriteslist.add(segment)

screen.fill(BLACK)

# allspriteslist.draw(screen)

for x in allspriteslist:
    x.draw(screen)

pygame.display.flip()

clock.tick(5)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You have the `Segment` hard-coded to use `WHITE`. Make it take the colour as a parameter instead.

Comment: and how do i do that?

Comment: In the same way it takes `x` and `y` as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Building on what Peter Wood says, you could modify `Segment` to accept a colour as one of its parameters:

```
class Segment(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, color):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([segment_width, segment_height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

You could also create subclasses of this for snake and apple segments:

```
class SnakeSegment(Segment):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y, WHITE)


class AppleSegment(Segment):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y, GREEN)
```

In the remainder of your code, you ensure all instances of segments that compose the snake are `SnakeSegments`, and those that represent apples are instances of `AppleSegment`:

```
snake_segments = []
for i in range(3):
    x = 400 - (segment_width + segment_margin) * 1
    y = 200
    segment = SnakeSegment(x, y)
    snake_segments.append(segment)
    allspriteslist.add(segment)

apple_segments = []
for i in range(1):
    x = 200 - (segment_width + segment_margin) * 1
    y = 100
    segment = AppleSegment(x, y)
    apple_segments.append(segment)
    allspriteslist.add(segment)

    ...

 segment = SnakeSegment(x, y)

snake_segments.insert(0, segment)
allspriteslist.add(segment)
```

This is what I see when I start the game:

[image]

For reference, this is the entire body of the modified code that I'm running:

```
import pygame
import random
import time

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

segment_width = 16
segment_height = 16
segment_margin = 4

x_change = segment_width + segment_margin
y_change = 0


class Segment(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, color):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([segment_width, segment_height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

        if self.rect.left < screen_rect.left:
            temp_rect = self.rect.copy()
            temp_rect.x += screen_rect.width
            screen.blit(self.image, temp_rect)
        elif self.rect.right > screen_rect.right:
            temp_rect = self.rect.copy()
            temp_rect.x -= screen_rect.width
            screen.blit(self.image, temp_rect)

        if self.rect.top < screen_rect.top:
            temp_rect = self.rect.copy()
            temp_rect.y += screen_rect.height
            screen.blit(self.image, temp_rect)
        elif self.rect.bottom > screen_rect.bottom:
            temp_rect = self.rect.copy()
            temp_rect.y -= screen_rect.height
            screen.blit(self.image, temp_rect)


class SnakeSegment(Segment):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y, WHITE)


class AppleSegment(Segment):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y, GREEN)


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption('Snakes')

allspriteslist = pygame.sprite.Group()

snake_segments = []
for i in range(3):
    x = 400 - (segment_width + segment_margin) * 1
    y = 200
    segment = SnakeSegment(x, y)
    snake_segments.append(segment)
    allspriteslist.add(segment)

apple_segments = []
for i in range(1):
    x = 200 - (segment_width + segment_margin) * 1
    y = 100
    segment = AppleSegment(x, y)
    apple_segments.append(segment)
    allspriteslist.add(segment)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_change = (segment_width + segment_margin) * -1
            y_change = 0
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = (segment_width + segment_margin)
            y_change = 0
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            x_change = 0
            y_change = (segment_height + segment_margin) * -1
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            x_change = 0
            y_change = (segment_height + segment_margin)

    old_segment = snake_segments.pop()
    allspriteslist.remove(old_segment)

    x = snake_segments[0].rect.x + x_change
    y = snake_segments[0].rect.y + y_change

    if x < screen_rect.left:
        x += screen_rect.width
    elif x + segment_width + segment_margin > screen_rect.right:
        x -= screen_rect.width

    if y < screen_rect.top:
        y += screen_rect.height
    elif y + segment_height + segment_margin > screen_rect.bottom:
        y -= screen_rect.height

    segment = SnakeSegment(x, y)

    snake_segments.insert(0, segment)
    allspriteslist.add(segment)

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # allspriteslist.draw(screen)

    for x in allspriteslist:
        x.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(5)

    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: @Kadosh If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: @Kadosh Can you elaborate on "doesn't work" (by providing updated details in your original post)?

Comment: i see only a black screen and when i click to quit it shows me the pictue that u showed me for like a fraction of a second

Comment: @Kadosh Yes...your original code did exactly that, except all segments were white. I resolved the specific question you asked, which was about using different colours for different segments.

Comment: but when i run my original code it runs ok with all white segments thats my only problom

Comment: @Kadosh I see the problem. You didn't indent your code properly in your original question. When asking questions, **please ensure your code indentation is correct**. Does this work now? If not, can you adapt the changes I've made to work with your original code?

Comment: @Kadosh I have that too. Again, try adapting the relatively minor changes I've made to your original codebase.

Comment: what do i need to do?

Comment: i am sorry for being stupid but i dont get what i need to do